# oracle linux instead of installing in virtualbox it runs emidiately I log in computer with lux pasword (here is stil ubuntu)

Tags: boot

I installed Oracle Linux in a virtual machine, and because I didn't have my computer plugged in, it shut down. Now, when the computer starts up, I first have to enter a login code in Ubuntu, and then the computer behaves as if it's a virtual machine, and all files and everything are now in Oracle Linux. How can I fix this?

Comment: If your base (host) system is Ubuntu, it would be useful if you could provide details. If not, Oracle Linux is off-topic for Ask Ubuntu.